# SQLite: Is closing and reopening a database a bad habit?

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I am creating a java program where I initialize the database when starting up the program.
I do that in a funtion(void) called `initializeDatabase()`:

```
public void initializeDatabase() {
    String statementCreateTableKlanten = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Klanten ("
            + "klantid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "adres TEXT,"
            + "postcode TEXT,"
            + "woonplaats TEXT,"
            + "telefoonnumer TEXT,"
            + "email TEXT,"
            + "opmerking TEXT"
            + ");"
            ;
    String statementCreateTableBestelling = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Bestelling ("
            + "bestelid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "klantid INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + "aantalpersonen INTEGER,"
            + "leverdatum TODO,"
            + "bezorgen TEXT,"
            + "email TEXT,"
            + "opmerking TEXT"
            + ");"
            ;

    executeStatement(statementCreateTableKlanten);
    executeStatement(statementCreateTableBestelling);
    //This repeated for 10+ statements
}
```

The functions I use to `executeStatement()`:

```
public void executeStatement(String statementStr) {
    Connection connection = connectToDatabase();

    try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        statement.execute(statementStr);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        closeConnection(connection);
    }
}

public Connection connectToDatabase() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
        System.out.println("Verbonden met SQLite database.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}

public void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
    try {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
            System.out.println("Verbinding met SQLite database gesloten.");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Is it a bad habit to connect and disconect from the database this often or would I be better of to open the connection, execute all the queries, close the connection?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes, it's considered a bad idea to open connections often as there is a lot of overhead on some database connection creations. And you are better off using some connection pool facility, especially if multiple threads are going to use your class.

Comment: It can not be generalized. It can be decided based on the requirement that you are fulfilling. In your case, if all the queries are to be executed one after other then yes you can open the connection, run all the queries and finally close the connection.

Comment: sqlite has a fair amount of overhead the first time you run a command on a newly opened database (It has to read and parse all the table, view, index, etc. definitions in the `sqlite_master` table). Better to have a persistent connection that gets repeatedly used over the life of your program.